# extracting lines from a multi-column file

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following format of data set:

```
Identified_____ID#2357_____ReadSequence:1238  
Unknown_____0_____ReadSequence:0979  
Unknown_____0_____ReadSequence:5476  
Identified_____ID#567899_____ReadSequence:4376
```

Using `awk` command, how can I extract the `ReadSequences` but only lines which have been identified (based on the first column entries)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F"_____" '$1=="Identified" {print $3}' test.in 
ReadSequence:1238
ReadSequence:4376
```

If you only want the ReadSequence ids, `gsub` is your friend:

```
$ awk -F"_____" '$1=="Identified" {gsub(/^.*:/,"",$3); print $3}' test.in 
1238
4376
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'_____' '/^Identified/ {print $NF}' file
ReadSequence:1238
ReadSequence:4376
```

OR

```
awk '/^Identified/ {split($0,a,"_____");print a[3]}' info
ReadSequence:1238
ReadSequence:4376
```

OR if you only want to read the value of ReadSequence then

```
awk -F'_____' '/^Identified/ {split($NF,a,":"); print a[2]}' file
1238
4376
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F':' '/^Identified/{print $NF}' file
1238
4376
```